# how to filter variables on a list that has multiple data.frame

Tags: r

if I have a list of data.frame `Datalist` and a variable list `Varlist`. How can I keep the variables that are in the varlist?

something like:

```
lapply(datalist,
              function(x) x <-x %>% select(any_of(varlist$Var.name)))
```

My codes did not work. I think I mess up the how to filter list vs data.frame.  New to R, very confuse on this now.  Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
result <- lapply(datalist,function(x) x[, varlist$Var.name])
```

Regarding your attempt try removing `<-` part in the code.

```
result <- lapply(datalist, function(x) x %>% select(any_of(varlist$Var.name)))
```

Comment: Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , Valst$Var.name) : 
  undefined columns selected
Called from: `[.data.frame`(x, , Valst$Var.name)

Comment: What does `dplyr` code return? Do you have `NA`s in `varlist$Var.name` ? It would be helpful if you could share a reproducible example of your data so that it is easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `intersect`

```
results <- lapply(datalist, function(x) x[intersect(names(x), varlist$Var.name)])
```

---

Or using `select` with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
results <- map(dataList, ~ .x %>%
                           select(any_of(varlist$Var.name)))
```